# Code metrics for my project

Tags: .net, metrics, code-metrics, code-complete

I would like a program that goes in my TFS and weekly takes a snapshot of different metrics like code complexity, Lines of code, code coverage and other stuff and displays them in a graph.

It would also be cool to see stuff by individual programmer, although I am not that worried about this as I think it would actually be detrimental to the team to measure at this level.

I cannot be the first person who has thought of this.  Does this sort of thing exist?

I will start by mentioning Sonar which appears to have historical C# code metrics.  There must be more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've answered your question by yourself :) Sonar IS what you're looking for :) For developer-based metrics you can see also the commerical plugin http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/developer-tools/developer-cockpit/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is more, there is the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). *Disclaimer I am one of the developer of the tool*.

NDepend collects more than [80 code metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx) on a .NET code base, including [code complexity](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#CC), [Lines of code](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#NbLinesOfCode), [code coverage](http://www.ndepend.com/Coverage.aspx)... It is very easy to create your own code metrics like the famous [C.R.A.P metric](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_C.R.A.P_method_code_metric.html).

The BuildMachine edition can be inserted into your [TFS Build Process](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_TFS.aspx), and generate HTML+javascript reports (see some [sample generated reports here](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx)).

[image]

[200 default Code Rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed and it is very easy to create your own Code Rules thanks to [code querying on LINQ (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). Code Rules can be validated in the [HTML+javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule) or/and in [inside Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx). Code Rules can deal with code metrics, code dependencies, OOP design, code diff, naming conventions...

With the Developer edition, NDepend is 100% integrated in Visual Studio 2012, 2010, and 2008. It can produce live [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx), [dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx) and [code metric treemap](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Treemap.aspx). Finally the tool has also some facilities to deal with [code diff](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Diff.aspx).

[image]

Comment: Does it do historical metrics as well?

Comment: It can diff metric like in this rule: http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_making_complex_methods_even_more_complex_(Source_CC).html  If you want historic metric, with multiple point in time, you'll have to use NDepend.API and load multiple analysis result: http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html